# Failed to start X server. REDHAT LINUX 5.3

Tags: linux, x-server

I installed Red-hat  5.3

problem is that it is not showing graphical interface.
only kernel / command prompt is available.

I tried startx, then I got this msg

*No video BIOS modes for chosen depth*

also showing that

ERROR: Failed to start X server.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. Actually at the installation time it asks whether you want to install a basic server or want to include desktop and some other features. By default the BASIC SERVER option is marked and hence it doesn't include the graphical interface. I reinstalled with the Desktop option and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that it cannot setup your video card for the resolution you've chosen. I would try running system-config-display as root, and failing that, I would go to IRC (Freenode) and lookup #redhat, explain the problem and let them talk you through the resolution.

Comment: I tried system-config-display 
...
Couldn't start X server with old config.
Trying with fresh config...then it waits for some time and after that it shows..

Failed to start X server.

Comment: Then head over to #redhat on freenode and talk to them, it's realtime and they're exceedingly helpful.

Comment: Someone told me that Redhat doesn't work on Mercury's motherboards.
Is it true? I have installed fedora 11 now and its working fine.

Comment: No clue, I've never tried one of Mercury's motherboards. Nor have I heard of any problems, though that's hardly definative. If fedora works, I would be inclined to believe that RH/CentOS 5.4 would work.